# Linux kernel function Doesn't return correct value?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I have change linux kernul to add this function (after adding new faild called my_field of type long):

```
asmlinkage long sys_set_weight(long weight) {
    if (weight < 0)
    {
        return -EINVAL; // -22
    }
    current->my_field = weight;
    return 0;
}
```

in syscall_64.tbl I have:

```
334 common  set_weight      sys_set_weight
```

and in syscalls.h I have:

```
asmlinkage long sys_set_weight(long weight);
```

in C when I wrote:

```
int set_weight(int weight) {
    long r = syscall(334, weight);
    return r;
}

int main () {
    int x = set_weight(-3);
    cout << "set_weight returns: " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I see the following printed:

> set_weight returns: 0

why is that? I am retuning `-EINVAL` not 0

Comment: Correct way for define syscall function in the Linux kernel is using a macro from `SYSCALL_DEFINE*` family. Since your system call has single parameter, you need to use `SYSCALL_DEFINE1`. Example of using this macro: [source/fs/file.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12/source/fs/file.c#L1192).

Comment: You could use `pr_info("%s(%ld)\n", __func__, weight);` to print something to the kernel log.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `syscall`, [you are passing through `...`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html). You pass an `int` through `...`, but the function expects a `long`.

I'm not sure why you made `set_weight` accept an `int` when the call expects a `long`, but you have no prototype that converts it to a `long` before passing it.

Comment: please note long in linux is int in c

Comment: Does the ABI guarantee they are compatible types?

Comment: _please note long in linux is int in c_ You're on a 64 bit machine so that is _incorrect_. David's analysis is correct. You want `int set_weight(long weight)` or `syscall(334,(long) weight)`